# Best testing Path for MCITP:Enterprise Admin

Tags: untagged

I have decided that my next goal is the MCITP enterprise admin. They have a [deal on testing](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/career/en/us/career-offer.aspx). What is the best path as far as which tests to take first? I am thinking of starting with the 70-640, but that is just because it is the first one on the list.

Comment: If you're only just starting out, make sure you get study material that covers 2008 R2 - the microsoft press books are yet to be updated and only cover 2008. These exams have been updated (as I am finding out at the moment). 70-642 was a beast with 75 questions over 3 hours...

Comment: any recommendations on a good text to study from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did and recommend: 640, 642, 643, 680, 647.

Note that 647 is notably harder than the rest. If you use these technologies in your normal job, then you shouldn't have much trouble passing the test. If you don't commonly use them, get the study materials or sign up for a class, especially for that last one.

Comment: I've been considering getting re-certified (my WinNT MCP is, um, dated) so this is good to know.

Comment: @sysadmin1138, I laugh when I look at my transcript and it still says MCP+I and all of those ancient certs from 12 years ago. I guess it adds a touch when a candidate has both old and new certs (you know they didn't just do it recently to get an interview), but the old ones have no other value.

Comment: it just seems kind of backwards to me, active directory before installing and configuring server. i mean i can configure server08 but it seems like AD would build on what was learned with server08

Comment: @EricCumbee Not so much. You install AD once, and then you install lots of servers. In fact, the vast majority of your server installs should be into a pre-existing AD tree (at least according to Microsoft) so that's where they focus.

Comment: @sysadmin1138 i had not thought about that fact. that makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

well for me,it is all about,background and intrest.i am coming from network environment,so i took 642 first and passed it,going towards 680,to microsoft it makes no sense which ever one comes first as long as 647 is the last.but if you take 640 and then 642 it will be easier to understand 642.but hey i am an exception.i prefered 642,680 and then 640 followed by 643 647

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://serverfault.com/questions/ask) button.